# Get peer's IP address when SSL peer authentication fails in Java/Netty

Tags: netty

I'm using Netty to build a mutual authenticated TLS connection. How can I get the peer's (client) IP address when the peer authentication failed?

I add SslHandler into the server's channel pipeline and try to get it when the channel is activated. The failure happens when getPeerPrincipal() is called and an exception is thrown. I try to print out the peer host and call getPeerHost() when handling the exception. But I only get null.

Any hints about this. Many thanks!

```
public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).handshakeFuture()
            .addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<Channel>>() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> future) {
                    try {
                        String peerX = ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).engine().getSession().getPeerPrincipal()
                                .getName();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        String peerHost = ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).engine().getSession().getPeerHost();
                        logger.error("Failed: with" + peerHost);
                        logger.error("Error in activating receiving channel", e);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the client's IP like this:

```
 Channel ch = ctx.channel(); 
 String peerHost = ((java.net.InetSocketAddress)ch.remoteAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress();
```

Comment: @user3674571 glad to help, It can help me if you click to accept the answer:)